# Hive CRUD, where clause and aggregation queries not working

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am running hive after setting up hive and hadoop on my system. I can create the tables and load the data in it via the hdfs or via local inpath query. But, I am facing an issue when running queries such as:

1. Insert Query(insert into table values(.....))
2. Where clause( from table where )
3. Aggregation(Count(*))

Now I am using the default settings to setup the hadoop core-site.xml and yarn-site.xml and mapred-site.xml as:

Core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
          <name>hadoop.proxyuser.username.groups</name>
          <value>*</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>hadoop.proxyuser.username.hosts</name>
          <value>*</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
                <value>/usr/hadoop/hadoop/tmpdata</value>
                <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
        </property>
<!--<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>-->
<property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>hdfs://<ip>:9000</value>
      <final>true</final>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
   <value>yarn</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
 </property>
 <property>
      <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
      <value>2250</value>
  </property>
 <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
      <value>3000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I am getting this issue while running any of the query:

[image]

What is that I am missing here in the configuration that is not letting to run these simple queries with not much data.

Link to setup Hive:
[Hive Installation](https://tecadmin.net/install-apache-hive-on-centos-rhel/)